# xna published project without content pipeline?

Tags: xna, publish, content-pipeline

I'm working on a personal project for learning purposes in XNA. I've read online that using the content pipeline requires people to have the xna runtime installed. So i've decided to load files using *Texture2D.FromStream*.

Everything is fine when I'm running the project from visual c#, but when I publish the project and run it, it crashed immediatly. I'm not sure if there is a way to see more info on the crash, but I assume not. I'm thinking it's down to not using the content pipeline.

When I look inside the application files for the published project I only see .xnb files. and no raw .png and .xml files that I'm using.

I tried to place the files in there manually but that didn't work aswell.
The files are all in the "Projectname\bin\x86\Debug\Content" folder.

Anyone has any idea?

---

**edit**

I have just rewritten my contentmanager so it uses the content pipeline, and the published project now works fine on my pc. So I have to figure out a way to get it to work without the content pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you work with Texture2D.FromStream, you have to care about two facts:

1. You have to change some resource's properties:

   - Compile action: None
   - Copy to result folder: Always

     This way the xnb won't be builded and you will get your resources instead
2. You have to set the appropiate path, now you have not "bin\Debug" in your path.

Comment: Thanks #1 did the trick!

Not sure what you mean with 2 though. Should I somehow remove the x86 folder?

Is there any downside to not using the content pipeline btw?

Answer (score 0):

As @Blau mentions, changing the image's properties will fix your problem. As you can see, the FromStream method is fully supported on the framework on all platforms now:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/05/10/image-codecs-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx.

As far as seeing errors ... you can always put a try catch around the statement that you think is throwing the error and then write out the error text to the screen so you can see it. Something like

```
try
{
    //The offending code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    WriteError(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that, was just wondering if I had a "real" debugging alternative or some kind of log.